# I was running 18.04 with communitheme, but after updating to 18.10 communitheme (yaru) is gone

Tags: themes, 18.10

There is no login option for communitheme as before and also there is no option to select the icon pack from tweaks. I've tried reinstalling the snap package for communitheme but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to get it back I really liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Communitheme was just a backport of Yaru for Ubuntu 18.04. It's the default theme of 18.10.

Just remove the PPA/Snap of the backport and select `Yaru` from Tweaks under "Applications"

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, it's not an option.